# Merge values to an array based on similar object key javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a return like this

```
[
{
    "tripw3": "1"
},
{
    "tripw1": "2"
},
{
    "tripw1": "3"
},
{
    "tripw2": "4"
},
{
    "tripw2": "5"
},
{
    "tripw3": "6"
},
{
    "tripw3": "7"
}]
```

and I want to make the above result be

```
[
{
 tripw3: ["1", "6", "7"],
 tripw2: ["4", "5"],
 tripw1: ["3", "2"]
}]
```

Until now I'm still confused to make this happen.

Comment: Do all object inside you array have this structure ? meaning they always have `tripw4` and only `tripw4` ?

Comment: no, I forgot to add it. tripw4 is just an example, sometimes it can be a mixture of tripw4 and tripw3, tripw2 and so on

Comment: Check out `Array.reduce`

Comment: @NovalRaihan please give us a better and more general example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cane easily acheve the result using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    tripw4: "1",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "2",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "3",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "4",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "5",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "6",
  },
  {
    tripw4: "7",
  },
];

const result = [arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach((k) => acc[k] ? acc[k].push(curr[k]) : (acc[k] = [curr[k]]));
  return acc;
}, {})];

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```